# Alternatives to libpurple?

Tags: libpurple

I have an application that will be the front end to a subscription service. I would like embed a channel agnostic messenger (gchat,msn,yahoo,facebook etc) in the application (there are a number of key business drivers for doing so). I have examined libpurple and it seems to have everything I need, but I believe if I were to include libpurple (even as a dll) in my deployment package, I would have to GPL my parent application.

This I believe, won't be an option (though it would be nice) - are there any alternatives to libpurple that have a less restrictive license?

Comment: libgreen? _rimshot_ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to Pidgin, but with less restrictive licensing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991867/is-there-an-alternative-to-pidgin-but-with-less-restrictive-licensing)